# How to differentiate $\int_{B(t)} f(x,t) dx$ with respect to $t$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$\int_{B(t)} f(x,t) dx$ is given and assume $x$ is an $n$ dimensional vector variable, $t$ is positive real variable and $f(x,t)$ is a sufficiently smooth function of both $x$ and $t$. Also $B(t)$ is a time varying region in the $d$ dimensional Euclidean space with sufficient smoothness conditions. Then what is the formula for differentiating the integral $\int_{0}^{t} f(x,t) dx$ with respect to $t$? Could anyone please explain?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Oh wait: how can $x$ be an $n$ dimensional vector if its extreme of integrations are $0$ and $t$?

Comment: Oops... I made a mistake. I will correct it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some clever guy has already thought about it: look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

**ADDENDUM**

In case you are interested in differentiating with respect to $t$ the function
$$
t\mapsto\int_0^t \dotsi \int_0^t f(x_1,\dots,x_n,t) \,dx_1\dots dx_n,
$$
just notice that
$$
\int_0^t \dotsi \int_0^t f(x_1,\dots,x_n,t) \,dx_1\dots dx_n
= \int_0^t g(x_n,t) \,dx_n
$$
where
$$
g(x_n,t) = \int_0^t \dotsi \int_0^t f(x_1,\dots,x_n,t) \,dx_1\dots dx_{n-1},
$$
so Leibniz rule can be applied iteratively.

Comment: That's for functions of the type $x\mapsto\int_a^bf(x,t)\,\mathrm dt$. How do you apply it in this context?

Comment: What do you mean? Swap the role of $x$ and $t$?

Comment: That's not important. What's important is that in the OP's question one must differentiate with respect to $t$ in two spots, since we are dealing with$$t\mapsto\int_0^tf(x,y)\,\mathrm dx.$$If it was, say$$t\mapsto\int_0^\pi f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx,$$then I would agree with you.

Comment: He means that $f$ is supposed to be $(n+1)$-ary, as $x$ is the collection of the first $n$ variables. Your link points to the solution if $f$ is binary. Of course there is some problem with the notation, maybe all the first $n$ variables should run from $0$ to $t$?

Comment: Guys, I don't  understand. Leibniz allows to differentiate with respect to $t$ the function $t\mapsto \int_0^t f(x,t)\,dx$. $x$ of course has to be a scalar variable, since the extremes of integrations are $0$ and $t$

Comment: @A.Pongrácz The function $t\mapsto \int_0^t\int_0^t f(x_1,x_2,t)\,dx_1\,dx_2$ is still differentiable through Leibniz rule: you just have to use it twice: $\int_0^t\int_0^t f(x_1,x_2,t)\,dx_1\,dx_2=\int_0^t g(x_2,t) \,dx_2$ where $g(x_2,t)=\int_0^t f(x_1,x_2,t)\,dx_1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm aware that $t$ is appearing both in the integrand and as an extreme of integration. That's what Leibniz rule is about

Comment: I think that is what the author of the post was interested in: he just missed the idea that it is possible to deal with those variables successively. So there is the answer. (You should put it in your answer.)

Comment: @Federico You are right. What I had in mind was just the [basic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Proof_of_basic_form) of the Leibniz rule.